# yii translation - words with multiple meaning

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, yiic

I am using Yii's translation functionality to translate characters from English to other languages. I sometimes come across a word that has multiple meanings, so I have to make it unique somehow. Is there someway to do this in Yii?

Documentation online only seems to mention plurals, params and a bit about breaking translations into sections per view.

Thanks